# Hide an element without CSS

Tags: javascript, css

If CSS is disabled, but JavaScript is not, how can I hide an element (a file input field, in my case)? None of the following will work, although they all work when CSS is enabled:

```
element.style.display = 'none';
element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
element.hidden = 'hidden';
element.hidden = true;
element.setAttribute('hidden','hidden');
element.setAttribute('hidden',true);
```

The only thing that can hide when CSS is disabled, as far as I know, is a hidden input field. Maybe that could lead to a solution. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "If CSS is disabled" --- what if HTML is disabled? Is there any real reason for such a strange requirement?

Comment: Not a very practical reason, kind of like a challenge.

Comment: I hope it's truth and it won't go to production ;-)

Comment: -1 because I don't feel that this question is actually useful. CSS is the language for styling HTML, and visibility control is part of styling.

Comment: -1 this is comparable to asking to bind click functionality with CSS instead Javascript.

Comment: Is this for 508 compliance?

Comment: Please don't down-vote **well asked questions** because you don't personally know the use case. As @goodbuoy highlights, the obvious use case is that many people with poor eyesight (among others) simply disable CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's an `input` element, you could change its `type` to hidden:

```
element.type = "hidden";
```

But be aware that this won't work in some IE versions. In that case, I think you'd need to create a new element, give it the `hidden` type, and swap them.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/gLvRz/

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete element from DOM:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

If you want to restore it later, you can store its HTML code (or a reference to element itself) in a variable. In case of form field, it may be required to store its value too and then restore the value after restoring element itself.

Also, consider using [`hidden` HTML5-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-hidden), though its support by browsers may be not too wide yet (and the attribute itself may be removed from HTML standard).

Comment: I've seen that. If you store only the contents - you won't know *where actually* to restore it.

Comment: @MaratTanalin—to restore the element, a reference can be kept and used later. E.g. `var elementCache = {}; elementCache[element.id] = element;`. Now the element can be removed from the DOM and restored later. You can also store a reference to its parent if necessary, e.g. `elementCache[element.id + '_parent'] = element.parenNode;`.

Comment: @RobG: parent is also not enough as well. `<div>foo<span>removeme</span>bar</div>`

Comment: The OP can put in an empty span as a placeholder, it just depends on what they are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could abuse the `AREA` element to hide something inside it.

```
//hide element
var hiddenContainer = document.createElement("AREA");
element.parentNode.insertBefore(hiddenContainer, element);
hiddenContainer.appendChild(element);

//show element
hiddenContainer.parentNode.insertBefore(element, hiddenContainer);
```